# How to let system switch different version of installed packages?

Tags: apt, package-management

Foc example if I had `libclang 3.4` and `3.5` installed, how do I switch?

```
aptitude search libclang

p   libclang-3.3-dev                                                                                                                                       - clang library - Development package                                                                                                                              
i A libclang-3.4-dev                                                                                                                                       - clang library - Development package                                                                                                                              
p   libclang-3.5-dev                                                                                                                                       - clang library - Development package                                                                                                                              
p   libclang-common-3.3-dev                                                                                                                                - clang library - Common development package                                                                                                                       
i A libclang-common-3.4-dev                                                                                                                                - clang library - Common development package                                                                                                                       
p   libclang-common-3.5-dev                                                                                                                                - clang library - Common development package                                                                                                                       
i   libclang-dev                                                                                                                                           - clang library - Development package                                                                                                                              
p   libclang1                                                                                                                                              - C, C++ and Objective-C compiler (LLVM based)                                                                                                                     
p   libclang1-3.3                                                                                                                                          - C interface to the clang library                                                                                                                                 
p   libclang1-3.3-dbg                                                                                                                                      - clang library                                                                                                                                                    
i A libclang1-3.4                                                                                                                                          - C interface to the clang library                                                                                                                                 
p   libclang1-3.4-dbg                                                                                                                                      - clang library                                                                                                                                                    
i   libclang1-3.5                                                                                                                                          - C interface to the clang library                                                                                                                                 
p   libclang1-3.5-dbg                                                                                                                                      - clang library
```